Vagrant install process stuck at VirtualBox Guest Additions
My vanilla Vagrant Ubuntu 24.04 install gets stuck at the same point at the VirtualBox Guest Additions. I tried multiple times, but every time it stops at the same step and message below:
XXXXXXX@XXXXXX-PC MINGW64 /d/vagrant/projects/project6
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64' version '0.1.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: project6_default_1722119127024_28694
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   6.0.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 7.0.14
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
[default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (7.0.20) and guest (7.0.14) do not match.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   6.0.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 7.0.14
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic is already the newest version (6.8.0-31.31).
build-essential is already the newest version (12.10ubuntu1).
dkms is already the newest version (3.0.11-1ubuntu13).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Copy iso file C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Mounting Virtualbox Guest Additions ISO to: /mnt
mount: /mnt: WARNING: source write-protected, mounted read-only.
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 7.0.20 - guest version is 7.0.14
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 7.0.20 Guest Additions for Linux  100%
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 7.0.14 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Setting up modules
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 6.8.0-31-generic.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until
the system is restarted or 'rcvboxadd reload' triggered
VirtualBox Guest Additions: reloading kernel modules and services
VirtualBox Guest Additions: kernel modules and services 7.0.20 r163906 reloaded
VirtualBox Guest Additions: NOTE: you may still consider to re-login if some
user session specific services (Shared Clipboard, Drag and Drop, Seamless or
Guest Screen Resize) were not restarted automatically

The Vagrantfile:
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Machine Image
  config.vm.box = "apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64"

  # Provisioning
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"
end


Can we see the contents of your Vagrantfile, and what command you ran to try to install the Guest Additions?

Sure thing, the Vagrantfile contents are very basic.
'Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
Machine Image
config.vm.box = "apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64"
Provisioning
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"
end
`

So 1. how did you attempt to install Guest Additions, and 2. what error logs do you have? All you've provided is normal install logs, where nothing is wrong.

Based on the output from vagrant I guess that you have installed the vagrant-vbguest plugin because I have also been using it and I ran into the same problem.
You can check if it is installed by typing vagrant plugin list. If the output shows something like vagrant-vbguest (0.32.0, global) then the plugin is installed.
I solved the problem by telling the vagrant-vbguest plugin that it shouldn't automatically install the guest additions. To do this open your Vagrantfile and after Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| enter the following code:
  if Vagrant.has_plugin? "vagrant-vbguest"
    config.vbguest.no_install  = true
  end

With this code the different versions of the GuestAdditions are reported but an automatic install isn't triggered. After the vm has started install the GuestAdditions manually.
I guess this is a bug in the vagrant-vbguest plugin. However as you can see on the plugin github page the development has been discontinued:

Please note that as of 2023-12-17, this project is archived and will not receive further updates or support from me.
However, the existing codebase will remain available for reference and use under the project's open-source license.
~ https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest

So maybe it's better to stop using it altogether.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I don’t remember installing vagrant-vaguest plugin explicitly. Does it gets installed automatically upon new installation?
I’ll try the code above and let’s see if it fixes the issue.

As far as i remember you need to install it manually. To see if it is installed type: vagrant plugin list. If the output shows something like vagrant-vbguest (0.32.0, global) then it is installed.
I have also updated my answer to contain this information.

Reran Vagrant up again and it worked this time.
